# Spectral decomposition of R matrix -> Wenzl projectors?

Tags: knot-theory, linear-algebra

Just curious: if you take a R matrix from knot theory and apply
a spectral decomposition (see. e.g. my following post
[Matrix decomposition the other way](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65332/matrix-decomposition-the-other-way))
you'll get projectors: $T_i*T_j=T_i*\delta_{ij}$.
Are they related to the Wenzl projectors?